# warning:cast to pointer from integer of different size

Tags: c

I'm not a c expert I have this warning building gimp

```
warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
  257 |   writer->output = g_win32_output_stream_new ((gpointer) fd, FALSE);
```

the function is

```
GimpConfigWriter *
gimp_config_writer_new_from_fd (gint fd)
{
  GimpConfigWriter *writer;

  g_return_val_if_fail (fd > 0, NULL);

  writer = g_slice_new0 (GimpConfigWriter);

  writer->ref_count = 1;

#ifdef G_OS_WIN32
  writer->output = g_win32_output_stream_new ((gpointer) fd, FALSE);
#else
  writer->output = g_unix_output_stream_new (fd, FALSE);
#endif

  writer->buffer = g_string_new (NULL);

  return writer;
}
```

How I can fix it?

Edit
From the documentations those are the definitions
https://www.manpagez.com/html/gio/gio-2.50.0/gio-GWin32OutputStream.php

https://docs.gtk.org/gio/ctor.UnixOutputStream.new.html

```
GOutputStream *
g_win32_output_stream_new (void *handle,
                           gboolean close_handle);

GOutputStream*
g_unix_output_stream_new (gint fd,
                          gboolean close_fd)
```

Edit2
So I'm thinking someting like
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/get-osfhandle?view=msvc-170

```
 writer->output = g_win32_output_stream_new (_get_osfhandle(fd), FALSE);
```

can it be good?

Edit 3
Solution

```
  writer->output = g_win32_output_stream_new ((void*) _get_osfhandle(fd), FALSE);
```

Comment: Does the build work?

Comment: It's happening because `fd` is being cast from `gint` to `gpointer` on Win32 systems. Is that necessary?

Comment: @Chris I added the document defnitions

Comment: @AlbertoAlibaba How was `fd` assigned?

Comment: The code is part of gimp, not written by the OP. If there's a bug to be fixed, it should be reported to the gimp project. https://www.gimp.org/

Answer (score 1):

This warning ...

> ```
> warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
>   257 |   writer->output = g_win32_output_stream_new ((gpointer) fd, FALSE);
> ```

... is complaining about the cast `(gpointer) fd`.  It suggests that the integer `fd` is unlikely to contain a valid integer representation of a pointer value, on account of it being narrower than a pointer.

And it's more than right.  `g_win32_output_stream_new()` requires its first argument to be a windows file handle, which is a pointer already.  If you had one then you would not need to cast.  If the `fd` parameter was derived from such a handle then you cannot rely on recovering the original handle by casting.  If it was *not* even derived from such a handle then the function call makes no sense at all.

The best fix would probably be to write a whole separate `gimp_config_writer_new_from_win32_handle()` function, with an appropriate parameter type and implementation, instead of trying to make `gimp_config_writer_new_from_fd()` do double duty.